# How do lisps that prefer first and rest to car and cdr approach combinations like cdaddr?

Tags: list, clojure, lisp, cons, cdr

One of the great schisms in the Lisp community is if we should have `car` and `cdr` or `first` and `rest`. One of the benefits of the traditional `car` and `cdr` is that we can combine them to produce pronoucible functions like `cdaddr`. How do Lisps that do not use `car` and `cdr`, such as Clojure, typically form combinations like this with `first` and `rest`? Is there any consensus?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see a schism, Clojure is more recent so it dropped a little historical bagage here and there but this is however a pretty minor detail

Comment: If there are lisps (I guess there is one) which only have `first` & `rest` they're making the treatment of conses as things out of which you can build structures which are not just lists as some secondary thing.  As an example, an alist is a list (`first` / `rest`) of *pairs* (`car` / `cdr`), not a list of lists.  (This doesn't make all the `cdaaaaddaddr` things more than a historical curiosity.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clojure, at any rate, simply has no need for caddaadr and friends, because nobody builds data structures out of just cons cells. The language does have combinations of any two of `first` and `next`, named `ffirst`, `fnext`, `nnext`, and `nfirst`, which were added very early on I suppose because it was assumed we'd want something like cadr, but I never see them used in real life.  Instead destructuring is used quite often.

On the rare occasions where you need to reach deeply into a structure built of nested sequences, destructuring often still produces readable code but also writing it out longhand is no great burden. It's also a good hint to you that maybe you should abstract thing a bit more rather than working with so many layers of primitive combinators directly.

Comment: @J.Mini The docs are all basically just like "Same as (x (y it))` - and the source is that (with some options to inline it)

Comment: (a) It's really easy to find such documentation with Google, and (b) it is not at all enlightening.

Comment: Also destructuring helps to reach into things.

Comment: @cfrick Good point. I suggest adding that as an answer, or editing it into mine.